# How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?

Tags: javascript, properties

I am using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517) to make a style object of all the inherited, etc. styles.

```
var style = css($(this));
alert (style.width);
alert (style.text-align);
```

With the following, the first alert will work fine, but the second one doesn't... it's interpreting the `-` as a minus I assume. The debugger says 'uncaught reference error'. I can't put quotes around it, though, because it isn't a string. So how do I use this object property?

Comment: Damon, addressing the ambiguity & confusion (reflected also by the divergent answers and the added/removed downvotes depending on interpretation...): did you specifically mean CSS properties, as hinted by your example & assumed by most answers, *or any JS properties*, in general, as indicated by the title and the lack of a `CSS` tag? [Yes, I know it's been 7 years. :) ]

Comment: @Sz. I meant `any js property` because i was having a problem with referencing a  property that had a hyphen in it (which also happened to be a css property... i didn't realize that there was another problem with what i was trying to do). So it's a weird one that ends up covering 2 different issues. but i'd say the top answer explains both issues.

Comment: I don't see anything at all in this question that is specific to jQuery. To me this is a ***pure*** JavaScript question. @jAndy, please excuse me for mentioning you here, but if you have the time and inclination, would you mind helping to settle the dispute whether this question is *about JavaScript* or *about jQuery*? (The question certainly *contains jQuery*. That we can all agree on, I think.)

Comment: This post is [being discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404829/1364007) on Meta.

Comment: See also: [Unable to access object property with “-” dash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13869627/1048572)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Look at the comments. You will see that for CSS properties, the key notation is not compatible with a number of properties. Using the camel case key notation therefore is the current way:

```
obj.style-attr // would become

obj["styleAttr"]
```

---

Use key notation rather than dot

```
style["text-align"]
```

All arrays in JavaScript are objects and all objects are just associative arrays. This means you can refer to a place in an object just as you would refer to a key in an array.

```
arr[0]
```

or the object

```
obj["method"] == obj.method
```

A couple things to remember when accessing properties this way:

1. they are evaluated so use strings unless you are doing something with a counter or using dynamic method names.

   This means obj[method] would give you an undefined error while obj["method"] would not
2. You must use this notation if you are using characters that are not allowed in JavaScript variables.

This regex pretty much sums it up:

```
[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*
```

Comment: key notation doesn't apply here - css defines styles using camel case in the keys:  http://jsfiddle.net/49vkD/

Comment: what browser? Fails for me on the hyphen gets in IE7, IE8, FFX 3.5.  And, by fails I mean displays "undefined" for both of those...

Comment: @brian tested in safari and chrome displays red, red, center, center.  I will try in ff now

Comment: @brian interesting, didn't work in firefox6, I didn't know that... learn something new every day

Comment: Yeah - I tend to err on the side of caution when it comes to making Chrome the authority ... Some very odd behaviors in chrome... for instance, chrome allows `this = <that>;`" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794369/how-to-delete-an-object-in-javascript-crossbrowser/6794533#6794533

Comment: Removed my downvote as another responder pointed out CSS collection happened to be the subject of hte question, but the actual question was how to get a hyphenated property.

Answer (score 35):

The answer to the original question is: place the property name in quotes and use array style indexing:

```
obj['property-with-hyphens'];
```

Several have pointed out that the property you are interested in is a CSS property. CSS properties that have hyphens are automatically converted to camel casing. In that case you must use the camel cased name like:

```
style.textAlign;
```

However this solution only works for CSS properties. For example,

```
obj['a-b'] = 2;
alert(obj.aB);          // undefined
alert(obj['a-b']);      // 2
```

Comment: @Brian You are correct for CSS properties. However, I was answering the original general question "How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?" Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49vkD/1/

Comment: indeed I narrowed the scope of the answers here on my own - I assumed the OP meant specifically style objects.  Removed my down-vote as the question was a bit more open ended than that.

Comment: I think you are correct. That is what probably what Damon wanted. I read it too literally.

Comment: You ***must*** use the camel cased name. Not *can*.

Answer (score 23):

CSS properties with a `-` are represented in camelCase in JavaScript objects. That would be:

```
alert( style.textAlign );
```

You could also use a bracket notation to use the string:

```
alert( style['text-align'] );
```

Property names may only contain characters, numbers, the well known `$` sign and the `_` (thanks to pimvdb).

Comment: the latter works.. one of those syntaxy things I just missed out on.  the script I referenced uses the regular css style names, but still useful to know about!

Comment: property names cannot start with numbers though

Comment: Property names can contain a vast ammount of Unicode characters. It's ok with the spec and it's ok with the browsers. For example: `var ò_ó = 'angry';`

Comment: **Do not use the second code.** CSS properties are camel-cased. Your code might work on some browsers but is not standard.

Answer (score 17):

Use brackets:

```
var notTheFlippingStyleObject = {
    'a-b': 1
};

console.log(notTheFlippingStyleObject["a-b"] === 1); // true
```

More information on objects: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

NOTE: If you are accessing the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) object, [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), you must use camelCase to access it from JavaScript. More information is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps).

Comment: You're not appeasing me - you're appeasing w3c standard, per numerous other responders to this question: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties, but upvoted just the same ...

Comment: **Do not use this code.** It's not that camel cased CSS properties are more cross-browser, it's that using hyphens instead of camel case is not standard and should not work.

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer the question: `style['text-align']` is how you would reference a property with a hyphen in it. But `style.textAlign` (or `style['textAlign']`) is what should be used in this case.

Comment: **Do not use this.** CSS properties are camel-cased. Your code might work on some browsers but is not standard.

Comment: Adjusted to use camel case.

Answer (score 5):

```
alert(style.textAlign)
```

or

```
alert(style["textAlign"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Hyphenated style properties are [referenced via camelCase in JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties), so use `style.textAlign`.

Answer (score 4):

**To solve your problem**: The CSS properties with hyphens in them are [represented by JavaScript properties in camelCase](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties) to avoid this problem. You want: `style.textAlign`.

**To answer the question**: Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/): `obj.prop` is the same as `obj["prop"]` so you can access property names using strings and use characters that are forbidden in identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

I think in the case of CSS styles they get changed to camelCase in JavaScript, so `test-align` becomes `textAlign`.

In the general case, where you want to access a property that contains non-standard characters, you use array-style: `['text-align']`

Answer (score 2):

The object property names are not one-to-one matches for the CSS names.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I wondered why the solution didn't work on my end:

```
api['data-sitekey'] // Returns undefined
```

...later on I figured out that accessing data attributes was different:

It should be like this:

```
var api = document.getElementById("some-api");
api.dataset.sitekey
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, but there is another wrinkle: if there are 2 hypens, the second one gets camelized, so `data-increment-value` becomes `dataset.incrementValue`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for modifying certain properties of element.style it sometimes require appropriate units such as ***px*, *rem*, *%***

For instance, instead of this

```
element.style.marginBottom = 12;
```

Try this

```
element.style.marginBottom = '12px';
```