# Javascript Object - Not able to access keys which contain '-'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

I have a Json of below format :

```
var response1="{" +
                        "\"code\":\"200\"," +
                        "\"requestID\":\"1002\"," +
                        "\"body\":\"[{" +
                        "\\\"author\\\":\\\"sumit\\\"," +
                        "\\\"id\\\":\\\"ABX-002\\\"," +
                        "\\\"title\\\":\\\"How to make Android APK in 2 seconds :)\\\"" +
                        "}," +
                        "" +
                        "{" +
                        "\\\"author\\\":\\\"sumit\\\"," +
                        "\\\"id\\\":\\\"ABX-002\\\"," +
                        "\\\"title\\\":\\\"How to make Android APK in 2 seconds :)\\\"" +
                        "}," +
                        "{"+
                        "\\\"author\\\":\\\"sumit\\\"," +
                        "\\\"id\\\":\\\"ABX-002\\\"," +
                        "\\\"title\\\":\\\"How to make Android APK in 2 seconds :)\\\"" +
                        "}" +
                        "]\"," +
                        "\"headers\":{\"Server\":\"Apache-Coyote/1.1\"," +
                                    "\"Content-Type\":\"text/xml\"," +
                                    "\"Content-Length\":\"131\"," +
                                    "\"Date\":\"Thu, 06 Sep 2012 09:10:26 GMT\"" +
                                    "}" +
                        "}";
```

I want to parse the Content-Type Key .
So I have written the below code to parse the value:

```
var jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(response1); 
var contentType  = jsonResponse.headers.Content-Type;
```

I am not able to get the value of Content-Type and Content-Length.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you double-escape the body JSON?

Comment: Hi Bergi ...I have made the response as String Object ,So I have added proper escape character to make it a proper Json String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the key is not a legal token, you must use a string as the key and use array syntax:

```
var contentType  = jsonResponse.headers['Content-Type'];
```

NB: this is not a "JSON parsing" issue, it's standard Javascript object access rules.