# Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash

Tags: javascript, json

I am unable to retrieve a value from a json object when the string has a dash character:

```
{
"profile-id":1234, "user_id":6789
}
```

If I try to reference the parsed `jsonObj.profile-id` it returns `ReferenceError: "id" is not defined` but jsonObj.user_id will return 6789

I don't have a way to modify the values being returned by the external api call and trying to parse the returned string in order to remove dashes will ruin urls, etc., that are passed as well.  Help?

Comment: It might help to add information on what language/parser you are trying to use to parse the JSON.

Comment: `Utilities.jsonParse` doesn't say much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

`jsonObj.profile-id` is a subtraction expression (i.e. `jsonObj.profile - id`).

To access a key that contains characters that cannot appear in an identifier, use brackets:

```
jsonObj["profile-id"]
```

Comment: Thanks! For information : It also work with angular : {{ jsonObj.attributes["profile-id"] }}

Comment: when this works in javascript and its the native implementation to access an object property key by string, sure it works in everything on top

Comment: Also works for JS "style" object!  @SLaks I extrapolated this solution to using the JavaScript style object for setting "box-shadow" property. `document.getElementById("someId").style["box-shadow"]="2px 2px 2px #616161";` works great!

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010: You should use `style.boxShadow` instead.  The `style` object converts hyphens to camelCase.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks... I like camel case,method better because less characters to type. Verified it works!!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869651), note that in Node.js if you access JSON with the array syntax `[]` all nested JSON keys should follow that syntax

This is the wrong way

```
json.first.second.third['comment']
```

And will give you the 'undefined' error.

This is the correct way

```
json['first']['second']['third']['comment']
```

Comment: Why is this an issue? The fist way looks completely normal. Is this a bug in the language?

Comment: If you want to go with this method. Consider using a functional utility like https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path

Answer (score 1):

For ansible, and using hyphen, this worked for me:

```
    - name: free-ud-ssd-space-in-percent
      debug:
        var: clusterInfo.json.content["free-ud-ssd-space-in-percent"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to apply the accepted solution to HomeAssistant value templates, you must use single quotes if you are nesting in doubles:

```
value_template: "{{ value_json['internet-computer'].usd }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux, try using the following template to print JSON value which contains dashes '-'

```
jq '.["value-with-dash"]'
```

It worked for me.