# How to catch the API response of type { "info-type" : [ {"1"} , {"2"} ] } in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am new to AngularJS. I know if the response is like `{ "info" : [{"1"},{"2"}] }` then in the promise

```
.then(function(data)){
   var i= data.info;
}
```

The above case I succeeded, but I want to catch the response, if the actual response is like `{ "info-value" : [{"1"},{"2"}] }` the promise will be:

```
.then(function(data)){
   var i= data.info-value;  // it is saying undefined
}
```

Comment: @nikhil are there any regex patterns ?? to catch  independent of response values

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with example?

Comment: maybe data['info-value']?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash

Answer (score 0):

Format of your response is invalid object.

```
{ "info" : [{"1"},{"2"}] }
```

It should be like this -

```
{ "info" : ["1","2"] }
```

You cannot define object with only key.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your response object ,If you are providing keys with object you should have to define them otherwise it would be an invalid object

like this:-

{ "info" : [{"1":''},{"2":''}] }