# How To Access JSON Keys With Hyphen

Tags: javascript, json

Normally, we access json object elements using dot notation i.e. `var obj = {"key": "value"}; var val = obj.key;`. How do we access the value in case of `var obj = {"key-with-hyphens": "value"};`? Do I have to revert to [] i.e. `var val = obj['key-with-hyphens'];`?

Comment: Using `obj['key-with-hyphens']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Answer (score 9):

You can access it with this notation:

```
var val = obj["key-with-hyphens"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> var obj = {"key-with-hyphens": "value"};
> obj["key-with-hyphens"];
< "value"
```