# How to call a variable in a .js object that has a '-' in it

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

the object "user" in

```
client.on("chat", function (channel, user, message, self)
```

looks like this.

```
'badges': { 'broadcaster': '1', 'warcraft': 'horde' },
'color': '#FFFFFF',
'display-name': 'target',
'emotes': { '25': [ '0-4' ] },
'mod': true,
'room-id': '58355428',
'subscriber': false,
'turbo': true,
'user-id': '58355428',
'user-type': 'mod',
'emotes-raw': '25:0-4',
'badges-raw': 'broadcaster/1,warcraft/horde',
'username': 'schmoopiie',
'message-type': 'action'
```

I'm trying to

```
console.log("the user: ", user.display-name);
```

but that returns undefined. How can I call it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Comment: user["display-name"] should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Use bracket notation

```js
var user = {
'badges': { 'broadcaster': '1', 'warcraft': 'horde' },
'color': '#FFFFFF',
'display-name': 'target',
'emotes': { '25': [ '0-4' ] },
'mod': true,
'room-id': '58355428',
'subscriber': false,
'turbo': true,
'user-id': '58355428',
'user-type': 'mod',
'emotes-raw': '25:0-4',
'badges-raw': 'broadcaster/1,warcraft/horde',
'username': 'schmoopiie',
'message-type': 'action'
};
console.log(user['display-name']);
```

Comment: solved my problem thanks, only issue I have now is "Error('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);" when I fs.writeFile("/cheerData.txt", "username: " , user['username'], function(err) {.