# How can my code below support the hyphen(-) character

Tags: json, validation, schema, json-schema-validator

"basicDetails": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "firstName": {
                            "title": "First Name",
                            "description": "First Name",
                            "type": "string",
                            "validation": "alphabetic.withSpaces",
                            "minLength":2,
                            "maxLength": 30

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)