# Reading out JSON using JavaScript

Tags: json

given is following JSON-File:

```html
{
   "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
   "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
   "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
   "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
   "type": "project",
   "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
   "support": {
       "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
       "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
       "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
       "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
       "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
   },
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "require": {
       "php": ">=5.4.0",
       "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
       "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
       "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0"
   },
   "require-dev": {
       "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
       "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
       "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
       "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
       "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
   },
   "config": {
       "process-timeout": 1800
   },
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
       }
   ]
}
```

How to read out property minimum-stability?
Following code fails by throwing out error:qnips_JSON_Loesung.html:112 Uncaught ReferenceError: stability is not defined

```
output+="<th class='spalte'>"+daten.minimum-stabilty+"</th></tr>";
```

By the way, following construct works quite fine:

```
output+="<th class='spalte'>"+daten.keywords+"</th></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved my problem:

```
for(let j in daten["require-dev"]){
output+="<label> Version "+daten["require-dev"][j]+"<br></label>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The - makes JavaScript think it's a calculation.

Either remove that when the file is created or access it like a map.

Comment: I can't manipulate the JSON-File. It's at a server! How to access like a map?

Answer (score 1):

Here **daten.minimum-stabilty** is being confused with this expression (i.e. **daten.minimum** - **stabilty**). It thinks to subtract between **daten.minimum** and **stability**

To access a key that contains **dash or other** characters that are not permissible to be appear as an identifier, use **brackets** notation like this

```
daten["minimum-stabilty"];
```

Have you tried like this to access the json key that contains `-` ?

```
var json_with_dash_key = daten["minimum-stabilty"];
output+="<th class='spalte'>"+ json_with_dash_key +"</th></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **daten["minimum-stabilty"]** should work fine

Other alternatives are also suggested in the older post related to this problem: [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)