# Parsing cache-control header value from response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, cache-control

I need to parse the cache-control header response to use it from caching the API response.

Sample response headers:

```
{"x-backside-transport":"OK OK","connection":"close","transfer-encoding":"chunked","access-control-allow-origin":"*","cache-control":"public, max-age=60","content-type":"application/json","date":"Thu, 05 Oct 2017 10:33:59 GMT","etag":"\"-161458570\"","x-powered-by":"Express","x-global-transaction-id":"429271565"}
```

I am using `console.log("------ CACHE VALUE----"+JSON.stringify(response.headers.cache-control));` but this seems to fail everytime.

Giving me the error: `ReferenceError: control is not defined`

But when it try the same with

```
console.log("------ CACHE VALUE----"+JSON.stringify(response.headers.connection));
```

I am able to print out log value successfully. Am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dash `-` is not applicable in JSON. You may want to try parse like below

```
response.headers["cache-control"]
```