# AWS IoT Rule startwith(), endswith() doesn't work with JSON attribute that has a hyphen in it's name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I want to use an AWS IoT Rule to trigger a specific lambda based on the value of a attribute of the incoming messages. 
It seems like the problem is because of a hyphen that is contained in the attribute name.

My message looks like this:

```
{
  "testdata": "abc",
  "test-data": "abc"
}
```

If I trigger a lambda by the following AWS IoT SQL it works:

```
select * from 'my/test' Where startswith(testdata, 'abc')
```

But it doesn't work if I use this SQL:

```
select * from 'my/test' Where startswith(test-data, 'abc')
```

Is it possible to escape the hyphen or is there another way to use attribute names with a hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

In the [AWS iot SQL reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-operators.html), a hyphen is a subtraction operator when used in the WHERE clause, so no you can't use it as a hyphen like you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this Stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash

Comment: Is there any way to escape this character? Or what other possibilities are there if I cannot just change the content of the incoming json?

Comment: The solution Excel r 8 mentioned is not working. I cannot even save the IoT Sql statement in the AWS console