# Issue in Deserializing JSON Response Data to List

Tags: c#, json

i having issues getting the elements in data into a list.

I want to be able to get `User_ID`, `Country`, `Continent` and other elements to a list after which i will do a bulk insert to the database.

**The Error i get** 
***Error Message 
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code***

***Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Country_API.Response]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.***

To fix this error either change the `JSON` to a `JSON` array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal `.NET` type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a `JSON` object. `JsonObjectAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a `JSON` object.

**This is the JSon Data returned from the API**

```
{
    "Status": "200 Ok",
    "Message": "Data retrieved",
    "Response": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "User-ID": "EAD001",
                "Country": "Ghana",
                "Continent": "Africa",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "ead1@yahoo.com",
                "Religion": ""
            },
            {
                "User-ID": "EAD002",
                "Country": "Senegal",
                "Continent": "Africa",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Email": "ead2@yahoo.com",
                "Religion": "Muslim"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to Deserilize but it throws the above error.. this is what i am trying

```cs
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string toJsonString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(toJsonString);
}
```

Json Model

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string User-ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Continent { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Religion { get; set; }

}
public class Response
{
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public IList<Data> data { get; set; }

}
public class Application
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}
```

How to i achieve this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358493/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-sy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize the List inside the object. You need to deserialize the entire object. Try this:

```cs
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string toJsonString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>(toJsonString);
    IList<Data> dataList = deserialize.Response.data;
}
```

Comment: This really help me out i will mark is as solved.. Thank you.

I have a field of my JSON that returns the name as ***User-Code***  with an hyphen when i create my JSON model with same ***User-Code*** in c# it rejects the naming convention and when i use ***User_Code*** the Model does not return anything.

How can i solve this?

Comment: @Haybee see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869651/7086678)

Comment: @FarhadZamani This is at the point of creating my c# JSON Model.  

when i do ***public string User-Code { get; set; }*** c# rejects the User-Code naming unless i use a User_Code with and underscore. Can you show an example?

Comment: You need to set a JsonProperty. Just type this above your field: [JsonProperty("User-Code")] @Haybee

Comment: Thank you.. This has been solved i had to use a Json Property to overide.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here . You have used "List" instead of "Response". bcoz in JSON "Response" is  object not a list

```
 var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(toJsonString);
```

use like this.

```
 var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(toJsonString);
```