# Parse Json returned with - character in a field

Tags: node.js

I'm using axios to call APIs
I received an API without patterns, and the return is:

```
{
    "pedidos": [
        {
            "cnpj": "09922334480001",
            "nr-pedido": "1234567",
            "os-cliente": "811",
            "data-entrada": "2020-08-03",
            "previsao-entrega": "2020-09-28",
            "status": "Em processo"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i parse JSON i use:

```
result.data.pedidos[0].status;
```

but when i have "-" in fields how can i call? When i use:

```
 result.data.pedidos[0].previsao-entrega
```

the error is returned.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
result.data.pedidos[0]["previsao-entrega"]
```

See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869651/12485722

Comment: When i split the code to previsao = result.data.pedidos[0] and after that previsao=previsao['previsao-entrega']

Answer (score 2):

For keys with `"-"` and other characters that won't work with dot (`.`) notation, use the bracket (`[` and `]`) notation instead, and enclose the key in quotation marks to make it a string:

```
result.data.pedidos[0]["data-entrada"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`result.data.pedidos[0]["previsao-entrega"]`

Comment: When i split the code to previsao = result.data.pedidos[0] and after that previsao=previsao['previsao-entrega']