# PugJS not interpolating numbers from json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, pug

I'm trying to render a list of interfaces I get from my router API. It is formatted as JSON. Pug is only rendering the strings and not the numbers.

Output (it renders properly in html):

```
em1 192.168.0.0/24
Address: 192.168.0.1    
Received Packets: NaN    
Sent Packets: NaN
```

The JSON:

```
(em1) / 192.168.0.1":{"name":"em1","flags":"0x8943","network":"192.168.0.0/24","address":"192.168.0.1","received-packets":2524179,"received-bytes":247344321,"sent-packets":2453592,"sent-bytes":1695092680},"
```

The Pug code:

```
div.container
        each interface in interfaces
            div.interface
                h2.interface-name
                    | #{interface.name} #{interface.network}
                p Address: #{interface.address}
                p Received Packets: #{interface.received-packets}
                p Sent Packets: #{interface.sent-packets}
```

For the life of me I can't find anything that tells me what to do with native numbers. I'm using nodejs and express with pug.

Comment: It appears the dash in the label names (received-bytes, sent-packets, etc) is causing problems. If I reformat the JSON manually to remove the dashes it will render the number. But the api calls come with the dashes. Do I really have to format the json to remove dashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answering my own question. It appears dashes in identifier names don't work. In order to access that item, throw brackets and single quotes around it. So the following works:

```
  div.interface
                h2.interface-name
                    | #{interface.name} #{interface.network}
                p Address: #{interface.address}
                p Received Packets: 
                    |#{interface['received-packets']}
                p Received Bytes: #{interface['received-bytes']}
                p Sent Packets: #{interface['sent-packets']}
```

Got this from: [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)