# @JsonbProperty does not function properly if there's a hyphen in the annotation

Tags: java, json, api, rest, json-deserialization

I have a self-generated client response class:

```
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbProperty;

    public class MyClass {
    
      @JsonbProperty("name-surname")
      private String nameSurname;
    
      //getter and setter
    }
```

the client response json is:

```
{
  "name-surname":"Jack Jones"
}
```

The problem is that the @JsonbProperty annotation does not work in this case and therefore the field is not read., is there a solution?

Comment: I don't understand your problem statement.  What special characters are you referring to?

Comment: You mean @JsonbProperty("nameSURNAME")` would have worked, the hyphen being the culprit?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 
yes, the output json of the service I consume expects the "-" in the name of the field and this causes the problem, the JsonbProperty does not recognize the field and does not deserialize

Comment: @JoopEggen 
yes, mocking the answer by removing the "-" in the name of the output field, and also removing it from the JsonbProperty, the field is correctly deserialized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Comment: @RobertHarvey 
unfortunately no, my problem is on java and not javascript, also the library used is import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbProperty and not JsonProperty

Comment: Can you simply strip the JSON of hyphens?