# HTTP Response not sending X-Auth-Token in Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I´m trying to make a post request to a third party API.

In this request I have to send my username and password on the header, and It will return a response header with the X-Auth_token. The problem is that I´m not getting the X-Auth-Token in the header if I make the posto from a client to my server and then to the API. If I make the request from Postman directly to the API url, it works fine.

This is the code:

SERVER

```
app.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("BODY", await req.body);
  try {
    const xToken = await axios.post(loginUrl, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

        "X-Username": req.body.username,
        "X-Password": req.body.password,
      },
    });
    console.log(xToken.headers);

    //res.send(xToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("SERVER Error: ", error.message);
  }
});
```

CLIENT

```
const signin = async () => {
  try {
    const TOKEN = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/signin", {
      username: "AGU",
      password: "MIOTTI",
    });

    
    console.log("TOKEN", TOKEN);

    return TOKEN;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("CLIENT Error: ", error.message);
  }
};

signin();
```

What can be the problem?

some data of postman:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the response header when you try to make the post with postman directly to https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/auth/getToken:

[image]

and this is the response header when you make the reques to the serven on express:

[image]

Comment: Can you share succussed Postman screen (Authorization, Headers, Body, POST URL and response statue) with hide private information? It will be help to understand which `auth` using in your `loginUrl` server.

Comment: @BenchVue I edited the post. See images. Need more?

Comment: Thanks for your updating, I think you missing send `Body`  part(x-www-form-urlencoded)`  the Key/Value list and received `Body` part with Status.(status 200?)

One more, I checked API documentation. https://apihub.primary.com.ar/
Can you point out `authentication` page? It should be help  the `X-Username`/`X-Password` format( base 64 or not). Some documentation shows `curl` example for get token. It will increase a percentage you get an answer.

Comment: @BenchVue idk if I understand you well, but are you saying that I did not send the content type x-www-form-urlencoded? Honestly I dont understand the explanation. Sorry I m noob.. XD

Comment: I can't test your `api.primary.com.ar` token, but I will answer with similar web site(spotify), You can apply your problem. Give me a 10 minutes, I will try answer your question.

Comment: I try answer it. It is not matched your direct case but you can leverage it. I think we can talk about a detail during convert into your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Server side as `server.js` file

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const corsOptions = {
    exposedHeaders: 'Authorization',
};

const app = express()
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(bodyParser())

const loginUrl = 'https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/auth/getToken'

app.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("BODY", await req.body);
    const response = await axios.post(
        url = loginUrl,
        '',
        config = {
            headers: {
                "X-Username": req.body.username,
                "X-Password": req.body.password,
            }
        })
    return res.send(response.headers["x-auth-token"])
});

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Listening on :3000") })
```

#### The Cliet side as `client.js` file

```
const axios = require('axios')
const signin = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/signin", {
            username: "<your id>",
            password: "<your password>",
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

signin()
    .then(token => {
        console.log('token is : ' + token);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

#### Install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors body-parser
```

Confirmed dependencies

```
$ npm ls --depth=0
@ D:\temp\working
├── axios@1.3.2
├── body-parser@1.20.1
├── cors@2.8.5
└── express@4.18.2
```

#### Run Server first

```
node server.js
```

#### Run client later

```
node client.js
```

Result in client
[image: ![enter image description here]

#### References

[Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

[Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Comment: OK, I resume. First step is I needs to success the Postmen with your credential Can you confirm three items?
First, header item, I added two items(X-Username/X-Password) from default Postman header. Correct?

Second is I needs Body section, can you shows your Postmen Body part?
The `x-www.form-urlencooded`'s Key/Value list, I have no information.
Third, can you shows your response body part. It will shows token and status.
Last item you can delete your credential. I copied it.

Comment: In your post request to the loginUrl you need to add on the header the x-username and x-password. Body is empty.

Comment: OK, I try to send message but No response of Body, just 200 OK, Did you got the access token?

Comment: The body responde is empty too. When you try directly making the request with postman, the response header has the X-Auth-Token. But nothing with my program

Comment: I think we are messed up. When you try with postman to make a post to https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/auth/getToken , with the X-Username and X-Password on header, it works OK. The response header has the X-Auth_token.
When you try to make the post with postman to the server on express, the response header doesn´t have the X-Auth-token.

Comment: I don't get it this means "The response header has the X-Auth_token."

Comment: one coment, the API: https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/auth/getToken is a third party one...
Every request you make, I dont get any information...

Comment: OK, I can get the `X-Auth-Token` information in header of response by Postman. Now first step done.
Let me try by code.