# How can I statically declare a Javascript object instance (a.k.a "associative array") whose property names (a.k.a keys) contain dashes?

Tags: javascript, object, static, variable-declaration

I want to statically declare a Javascript object (sometimes referred to as "associative array" when used as such) whose property names ("keys") contain dashes?

Without dashes (works):

```
myObject = {field_1:"aaa", field_2:"bbb"};
```

With dashes (results in syntax error):

```
myObject = {field-1:"aaa", field-2:"bbb"};
```

(And yes, I'm fully aware that such properties containing dashes [can only be referenced by using "bracket notation" rather than "dot notation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it), but that's a completely other story, I'm only talking about the case of static declaration of such objects here.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17574355/4642212

Comment: FYI, it's called *bracket notation* and *dot notation* (the notation has nothing to do with arrays). And no, this is actually closer related than you think. You have to use bracket notation + a string literal if the property name is not a valid identifier name. Similarly for object literals, you have to use a string literal if the property name is not valid identifier name. Same reason, same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to wrap the property names in quote to read "field-1" as a string.

```
var myObject = {"field-1":"aaa", "field-2":"bbb"}
console.log(myObject["field-1"], myObject["field-2"])

//computed properties
var name1 = "field-1"
var name2 = "field-2"

var myObject = {
     [name1]: "aaa",
     [name2]: "bbb"
}

console.log(myObject["field-1"], myObject["field-2"])
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! (please change "bbbb" to "bbb" in the "computed properties" example code though, for consistency and to avoid unnecessary confusion)

Answer (score 2):

Inside an object literal, property names can be defined in *four* ways:

- as an [identifier name](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-identifier-names) (`foo`)
- as a number literal (`42`)
- as a string literal (`'foo bar'`)
- as a computed property (`[foo + 'bar']`)

`field-1` is neither of those. It's not an identifier because the character `-` is not valid in identifier names. It's relatively easy to know whether something is a valid identifier name: If it's not a keyword and not a valid variable name, it's not a valid identifier name. That is, since it's invalid to declare the variable

```
var field-1 = 42;
```

you cannot use it in a object literal either.

You have to use a *string literal* instead. A string literal can contain any character sequence:

```
myObject = {'field-1':"aaa"};
```