# Unable to use aria-hidden attribute as javascript object

Tags: javascript

You can see I'm checking `help.aria-hidden === "true"`
But it doesn't work.
What's wrong, please help.

Thanks.

```
function Help() { // Help
    var help = document.getElementById("help_content"),
        overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

    function closeHelpAndOverlay() {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        textarea.focus();
    }

    if (help.aria-hidden === "true") {
        closeHelpAndOverlay();
    } else {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        textarea.blur();
        document.getElementById("overlay").onclick = function() {
            closeHelpAndOverlay();
        };
        document.onkeydown = function(e) { // esc to close help
            if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.which === 27) {
                closeHelpAndOverlay();
            }
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the period syntax for a property that contains a hyphen (as the hyphen is interpreted as the subtraction operator). Use the bracket syntax:

```
if (help['aria-hidden'] === "true") {
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that it isn't a hyphen, it's the subtraction operator.

Comment: @benekastah: Yes, I thought the same and just added that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting that by calling `Help()`, you'll also be calling `closeHelpAndOverlay()` immediately upon reaching line 5? It seems you might be thinking that, but it's not the case. You need to explicitly call `closeHelpAndOverlay()` after you define it.

If that's not the problem you're encountering, please clearly state what you need help on. "It doesn't work" isn't something people can help you with.