# How to call object and its method with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have a bunch of jQuery objects with a init method, so right now I have something like this

```
$.myobject1.init(somevar);
$.myobject2.init(somevar); 
$.myobject3.init(somevar);
$.myobject4.init(somevar);
$.myobject5.init(somevar); // somevar is the same var in all the calls
```

but I'm looking for a way to simply this code, something like this

```
var objectName = "myobject1"; // or any other object name
$. objectName .init(somevar);
```

thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: Does `$[objectName].init()` not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Comment: the answers look good, but if you do want to do it with strings, remember in javascript foo.bar == foo["bar"]. so $["myobject1"].init(somevar) should do what you want for the second code piece.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are already jQuery objects you don't need $. and you can use .add() like this :

```
var object = myobject1.add(myobject2).add(myobject3).add(myobject4).add(myobject5);
object.init(somvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$[objectName].init(somevar);
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, all objects are maps. it's really weird, but it means you can do this trick:

```
var p = "mypropertyname";
var obj = {};
obj[p] = somevalue;
```

then, if you do:

```
console.log(obj.mypropertyname)
```

you'll get:

```
> somevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to loop through the names of your objects, then you should know that you can't combine strings with dot notation:

```
var someObj = {
    subObj: {
        a: 5
    }
};

someObj.subObj.a === 5;       // true
someObj."subObj".a === 5;     // throws error
```

But you can use strings with square bracket notation:

```
someObj["subObj"].a === 5;       // true

var propName = "subObj";

someObj[propName].a === 5;       // true
```

So you can use that to loop through your object names with a for loop, or you can use a jQuery method as suggested in other answers.