# GET variable name contains dash creates problems for req.query for NodeJS Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a GET endpoint that handles this variable in Node.js using Express:

```
?message-timestamp=2012-08-19+20%3A38%3A23
```

I'm having trouble accessing it using req.query. Accessing req.query.message-timestamp throws an error ("ReferenceError: timestamp is not defined"). Clearly the dash isn't playing nice.

Any obvious way around that?

Comment: does `req.query['message-timestamp']` work? can't you dump `req.params`? why not use `+new Date()` which gives something like `1396159446837` ?

Comment: Aha, didn't know about bracket syntax. Yes, using Date.now() now, but was asking just for future reference. Thanks! Edit: Also the callback in question comes from a texting service API, so the time that the message was sent isn't always the current time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In javascript, object values can be accessed by using either `.` or `[]`
When the key contains a dash, you cannot use the `.` notation because the `-` will be interpreted as "minus". This is not related to `express`, it's just how javascript works.

So you should use:

```
req.query["message-timestamp"]
```