# textarea naming conundrum - working with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, textarea

I have a form with multiple inputs. One of the inputs is a text area. Here is the beginning of its opening tag:

```
<textarea id="edit-about-me-input" class="edit-website-input" type="text" name="edit-profile[byc_about_me]"...
```

As you can see, I have chosen to name it as an array, so that, when I post the form, I only have one array of values to deal with.

However I am running into a problem when trying to run a javascript function on that name.

Here is the rest of the text area's declaration:

```
onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.edit-profile[byc_about_me],this.form.countdown,1000);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.edit-profile[byc_about_me],this.form.countdown,1000);"><?php echo $byc_about_me; ?></textarea>
```

Obviously, javascript does not like the dashes and brackets. Does anyone have a solution for me? Can I give it two names or something or do I need to rewrite the php that processes this form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use square bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the `edit-profile[byc_about_me]` property of the `form` object, like so:

```
this.form['edit-profile[byc_about_me]']
```

It's not pretty, but it works!

Related: [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)