# Json object with dash (-) character on element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm parsing a `json` object that contains an element named `data-config`.

ex:

```
var video = data.element.data-config;
```

Whenever I parse this element I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: config is not defined
```

The `ReferenceError` doesn't mention `data-config` but simply `config`.
Any idea why I'm getting this error?
Is this related with the dash (-) character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Valid Characters

In general JavaScript, variable/function names can't contain `-`. They can only contain **letters**, **$**, and **_ (Underscore)**

### So...

The error is coming because it's parsing:

`var video` is equal to `data.element.data`(valid) minus `config`

### Solution

Because variables can't contain dashes, you need to use what I'm going to call *String/Bracket Notation*

`data.element['data-config']`

If you need to do more then one, do

`data.element['data-config']['child']`

I don't recommend using *String/Bracket Notation* when you don't have to, it's better practice.

Comment: That's why I love SO, it works! I'll accept your answer in 10m. tks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `[]` notation when object properties contain special characters

```
var video = data.element['data-config'];
```