# meteor collection query in mongo console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I have a peer set up the collection's name to

`UserSettings = new Mongo.Collection("user-settings");`

When I tried to query in MongoDB console, I am not able to do

```
 db.user-settings.find()
```

i get this error :-

> ReferenceError: settings is not defined

How should I query a collection's name with dash?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `user-settings` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript and as such cannot be used to access the field using the dot notation.

It is actually interpreted as 2 expressions with a minus (`-`) operator between them.

You can use `db.getCollection('user-settings')` to get it.

Answer (score 5):

@MasterAM is right, the other way could be

```
db["user-settings"].find()
```

Comment: Yepp, or that (known as "bracket notation") :) BTW, consider using an underscore (`_`) instead of the dash to make it a valid identifier.