# Adding meta tag in javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file in whcih I am trying to add "meta" and "css" tag. I am getting the error as "Syntax error". Below is the code tried:

```
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = 'myCss';
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'site url/css/CustomStyle.css';
    link.media = 'all';

   var meta  = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.name   = 'viewport';
    meta.initial-scale  = '1';
    meta.content = 'width=device-width';

   var link1  = document.createElement('link');
    link1.id   = 'BootstrapmyCss';
    link1.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link1.type = 'text/css';
    link1.href = 'site url/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css';
    link1.media = 'all';

    head.appendChild(link);
    head.appendChild(link1);        
    head.appendChild(meta);
```

I am getting an error in the line as "Syntax error"

```
meta.initial-scale  = '1';
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try: `meta["initial-scale"] = '1'`

Comment: You can't have dashes in a variable names. Try to use `meta['initial-scale']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `-` as a part of variable name, because it is interpreted as minus (Subtraction) operator.

To fix this, use can use [`setAttribute`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) method, like this:

```
meta.setAttribute('initial-scale', '1');
```

or just replace that line with `meta['initial-scale'] = '1';`

Answer (score 4):

you can replace `meta.initial-sacle = '1';` with `meta['initial-scale'] = '1';`

Answer (score 3):

```
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = 'myCss';
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'site url/css/CustomStyle.css';
    link.media = 'all';

   var meta  = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.name   = 'viewport';
    meta['initial-scale']  = '1';
    meta.content = 'width=device-width';

   var link1  = document.createElement('link');
    link1.id   = 'BootstrapmyCss';
    link1.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link1.type = 'text/css';
    link1.href = 'site url/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css';
    link1.media = 'all';

    head.appendChild(link);
    head.appendChild(link1);        
    head.appendChild(meta);
```

Answer (score 0):

`meta['initial-scale']  = '1';` not valid on `typescript` way.

Try this.

```
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = 'viewport';
meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1';
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
if (head) {
    head[0].appendChild(meta);
}
```