# unable to access JSON child elements

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I was trying to iterate following JSON object. when i try to access the **content-items**  using **page.content-items** getting error.Is it not possible to access an object which have a key with "-"?.Please give a solution how to access this object.

```
{
      "page": {
        "title": "Romantic Comedy",
        "total-content-items" : "54",
        "page-num-requested" : "1",
        "page-size-requested" : "20",
        "page-size-returned" : "20",
        "content-items": {
          "content": [
            {
              "name": "The Birds",
              "poster-image": "poster1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Rear Window",
              "poster-image": "poster2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Family Pot",
              "poster-image": "poster3.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `page.content-items` => `page['content-items']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access the key with the `-` character, but not using dot notation. You need to use brakcet notation:

```
page['content-items']
```

to access the property.

Answer (score 1):

Just use string value like in arrays:

```
page['content-items']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `page['content-items']` because `content-item` is not a valid JavaScript identifier.