# underline text with click of a button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JavaScript what am i missing here? When i click on me click me i want the text to change to underline.

```html
<p id="demo" style=" 
text-decoration:none;

">Hello JavaScript!</p>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.text-decoration='underline'">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `style.text-decoration`. Change that to `style['text-decoration']`:

```html
<p id="demo" style=" 
text-decoration:none;

">Hello JavaScript!</p>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style['text-decoration']='underline'">Click Me!</button>
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it).

Comment: Or `style.textDecoration`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use textDecoration instead of text-decoration.

```html
<p id="demo" style=" 
text-decoration:none;

">Hello JavaScript!</p>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.textDecoration='underline'">Click Me!</button>
```