# How to set an environment variable from the Response Body in Postman where the concerned keyword is hyphenated

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to set an environment variable by capturing a node from the Response Body of an api, where the node contains two hyphenated words.

My  script is - `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", jsonData.access-token);` - This keeps returning **ReferenceError: token is not defined**

The node in the Response Body is - `{"access-token": "<token>"}`

I have tried using this script - `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", jsonData.access/-/token/);` - This script sets the keyword "Token" as an environment key but does not capture the value of the actual token from the Response Body.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", jsonData.access-token);

Comment: I would suggest you to use the stand alone version of Postman, the chrome extension is not used often these day

Comment: I am using the stand alone version of Postman

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ReferenceError: token is not defined

This indicates that token is expected as a distinct variable, but can't be found.

> postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", jsonData.access-token);

The above statement has invalid JavaScript syntax, as variable/object property names can't have a hyphen within them. More on valid names here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

This can be fixed by using the square bracket notation as follows:

```
pm.environment.set("Token", jsonData["access-token"]);
```

Note that the `postman.*` family of functions is deprecated and has been replaced with their `pm.*` equivalents. More details can be found here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to get token from response and set it in enviroment variable

```html
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
console.log(responseJson);
if(typeof responseJson.access_token !== 'undefined'){
    pm.environment.set("gateway-access-token", responseJson.access_token);
}
```