# how can i resolve hyper declaration error in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have an object defined as:

{
"IP-Address":"1.1.1.1",
"name":"User1"
}

in HTML

{{data.IP-Address}}

It shows an error `The righthand side of arithmetic operator must be type 'any'`.
Because of Hyphen(-).
How can I resolve that?

Comment: its interpreting it as (data.IP) minus (Address).

You can use a array style notation like ```data["IP-Address"]```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a javascript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
{{data['IP-Address']}}
```

But I'd also suggest to manage more simple property names so you may use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) in case it could be useful on your app.

So you could do this

```
{{data?.ipAddress}}
```

and prevent possible error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null.
```

in case you're rendering when your object is still null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code to `{{data['IP-Address']}}`