# How to use Hyphen(-) between two strings in angular 9 ngIf condition

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have an If condition in html to check permission to access a particular page :

```
    *ngIf="permission?.product-report?.list_product_report"
```

product-report is a static name which gives directly to the condition

When I execute it, got an error as below:

```
    Property 'report' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'.
```

Why this error occurs ? Someone please help me..

Comment: It should be `product_report` not `product-report`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer: I want product-report .

Comment: In your question - `"product_report is a static name"`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer : if i changed this here ... then i need to chnage many pages... So any other solution for this particular problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to use an inelegant solution of mixing dot notation and bracket notation

```html
*ngIf="permission['product-report']?.list_product_report"
```

The above solution might throw an error when `'product-report'` is defined and `list_product_report` is not. I'm not sure of the behavior when safe navigation operator is appended to a property fetched using bracket notation. Here you might have to forgo the safe navigation operator and check each property manually.

```html
*ngIf="permission 
  && permission['product-report']
  && permission['product-report']['list_product_report']"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **square bracket** notation to get that **`key`**

For Example

```
  <div *ngIf="permission && permission['product-report'] && permission['product-report']['list_product_report']""></div>
```

Comment: This would throw `undefined` errors in the console during run time if either of the properties `'product-report'` or `'list_product_report'` aren't defined. Each has to be checked individually: `*ngIf="permission && permission['product-report'] && permission['product-report']['list_product_report']"`

Comment: yes Michael typo mistake