# Create a new array on the basis of id in angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am getting below responses from 2 api calls. First I'm calling 1st api and getting below respose

first response I'm getting from 1st api call

```
dataName =   [
{
"id": "1",
"name": "stage1",
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "stage2",
},
{
"id": "3",
"name": "stage3",
}
]
```

In dropdown i'm display name values

```
 <mat-select (selectionChange)="onOptionsSelected($event)"required placeholder="Choose Data Name">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of dataName" >
                {{obj.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

On selection of name from first dropdown I need to call a different api which will give me below response

```
cluName = [
  {   
"cname": "cname1",
"id": "3",
 },
 {   
"cname": "cname3",
"id": "2",
 },
 {   
"cname": "cname1",
"id": "2",
}
]
```

On dropdown selection when selecting name I need to send the ID instead of name to match the cname associated with the ID and display in another dropdown.

Suppose if I select stage2 then I need to send ID :2 and match in second response its associated cname(cname3,cname1) and display those cname in second dropdwon. How to achieve this please help.

On selectionChange I tried following method

```
onOptionsSelected(event) {
 this.newArrayCluster = [];
 this.cluName.forEach(element => {
 this.newArrayCluster.push(element.find(item => item['id'] === 
event.value))});
console.log(this.newArrayCluster); 
 }
```

But I'm getting error "element.find is not a function".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also in the response from first call the property is `name` whereas in the HTML template it's `datacenter-name`. Which is the right name? Also if the object property has an hyphen `-`, it's better to access it using bracket notation `obj['datacenter-name']` rather than dot notation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122629/6513921

Comment: Yes i edited the code its name

Comment: I have updated the code with the method I tried so far

Comment: I can't explain the code right now, but try to gather info from this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-rnwg71?file=src/app/app.component.ts) implementation. Hit up here if you have any question.

Answer (score 2):

you must do like this
in your Html file

```
 <mat-select  (selectionChange)="onOptionsSelected($event)"required placeholder="Choose Data Name">
              <mat-option [value]="obj.id " *ngFor="let obj of dataName" >
                {{obj.datacenter-name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

Comment: But how I will iterate the second array and get the matching value of cname with the id?

Comment: You can also use  `let dataArr = dataName.filter(data => data.id == value )`

Answer (score 0):

*please follow given below link it would help ful for you first you should make relation between two array *

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvqqgc