# How to call SCSS 'parent selector reference &' to react css module?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

> This is my SCSS style for .br

```
 .br {
          &--red {
            border: 2px solid red;
          }
          &--green {
            border: 2px solid rgb(32, 170, 8);
          }
        }
```

> This is my nextjs react code:

```
import layout from "../styles/layout.module.scss";

export default function Index() {
  return (
      <div className={layout.br}>
        <h1>Khan</h1>
      </div>
  );
}
```

**How to access this ".br--red" in jsx?**

```
.br{ 
    &--red{
        border:2px solid red; 
          }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `dash` in an object's properties name(in this case, it's class name), for use of it you must use `Bracket notation`, and your property name should be in `' '`(quotation or double-quotation).

```
<div className={layout['br--red']}>
    <h1>Khan</h1>
</div>
```

You can read more about it in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) article.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on the comment above, you can also use dynamic variable in the brackets like so using backticks.

```
className={styles[`br--${color}`]}
```