# Put special characters inside JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a json and it has special characters inside.

```
myJSON = "metadata": Object {
  "album-art": "album-art.png",
}
```

However - Variable declaration is not possible due to the special character "-".

```
const Variable = myJSON.album-art
```

Can I put it inside a variable?

Comment: you can do `myJSON["album-art"]`

Comment: Also: [How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a better practice to use `_` instead of `-`,
but you can access the variable using `myJSON["prop"]`

```js
myJSON = {
  "album-art": "album-art.png",
}

console.log(myJSON["album-art"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this.
There are two methods to access a property/method in a object. One is dot notation and the other is square bracket notation (example below)

`const Variable = myJSON['album-art']`